# Rails doesn't show background-image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, precompile

I have custom CSS file style.css, not in application.css:

```
background-image: url('book.png');
```

I did

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

but it doesn't show image. Also I gave permissions to image(755). How can I solve it?

And there is no errors in console

log/production.log

```
I, [2014-12-24T01:22:04.323979 #27157]  INFO -- : Started GET "/login" for 81.21.82.67 at 2014-12-24 01:22:04 -0500
I, [2014-12-24T01:22:04.329702 #27157]  INFO -- : Processing by BookController#login as HTML
I, [2014-12-24T01:22:04.333589 #27157]  INFO -- :   Rendered book/login.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
I, [2014-12-24T01:22:04.334700 #27157]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 2.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

When I open from browser http://example.com/assets/book.jpg it doesn't open, too

Comment: @Nithin what in addition can I write for you?

Comment: where does book.png live?, and are you getting a 404?

Comment: Does it work in development?

Comment: @Doon in app/assets/images/book.png. No, there is no errors here. It was, but now it disappeared

Comment: where have you tried to display the image, show us the view...

Comment: @Nithin it's just <section class="wrapper"></section> with background-image.

Comment: Well, to make it work just append assets to the url. like this `background-image: url(/assets/book.png)` I use this very often and I don't have to rename the file to `scss` either. It should work in the production mode also. Let me know of that helps

Comment: @PamioSolanky no. In this case the url equals to /assets/assets/book.jpg

Answer (score 1):

After precompile image path will be changed so you need to use asset_path for get correct image path from asset.

If you use asset_path then it will be easy to get image after precompile.

Use this:

```
background-image: asset_path('book.png');
```

instead of:

```
background-image: url('book.png');
```

Comment: Its working fine over here. Can you please paste your class over here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the book.png is a local image, there are probably two changes you need to make:

a. Change `style.css` to `style.css.scss`

b. Replace the `background-image: url('book.png');` with `background-image: image-url('book.png');`

This ensures that the CSS uses the full asset URL for the book.png image.

Comment: RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  (in /usr/local/projects/book/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)

Answer (score 0):

**[Guides are your friends](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb).**

The problem is that assets in the asset pipeline are **renamed** to include a checksum that reflects their content. The problem with that is, that the link to the actual image is different than the one you expect. Only in production, since assets are only precompiled for production environments. In development there's no problem, because assets are recompiled in-place after any change and served with parameters that minimize possible caching.

**It's for the greater good.** The result of this is that if the file changes in the new release, it gets the different name when served (even if you didn't rename it yourself), so browsers and caching systems detect the change immediately and request the new asset. No pain with cache invalidation.

**ERB is used during asset precompilation**, and you can use it by adding `.erb` to file name, like `login.css.erb`. There is [an example in the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb).

```
.class {
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>)
}
```

The guides even describe a way of embedding an image right into CSS in *base64*. It works well with small images linke PNG icons, one less request and only +33% to image size.

```
#logo {
  background: url(<%= asset_data_uri 'logo.png' %>)
}
```

Comment: RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...und-image: url(": expected ")", was "<%= asset_path ..."
  (in /usr/local/projects/book/app/assets/stylesheets/login.css

Comment: @alizade Are you using Sass/SCSS in that stylesheet? There is a helper in Sass-rails that allows you to reference Rails assets. Or maybe you're importing it with Sass' `@import`? That case is covered by @PeterGoldstein's answer.

Comment: no, my file is login.css, not .scss and I do not import anything

Comment: @alizade Ah, gosh, I get it. In guides it's mentioned to rename the file to `whatever.css.erb` for it to get evaluated by ERB. Will add it to the answer soon, try in the meantime.

Comment: @alizade Now that's weird. Look up what's in the actual file and if there's a corresponding image in the `public` folder.

Comment: There is a possibility that your app does not serve assets at all (as they are static files), it's disabled by default in `config/enviroments/production.rb`. It is typically delegated to a reverse proxy, which is usually `nginx`. Then it shouldn't load any assets at all: no CSS, JS or images. Is that the case?